# Blender 2.8 bevel broken

Tags: modeling, bevel

Following this tutorial:

https://youtu.be/lZPedlX6CMw?t=813

when I try to bevel a circle I get:

[image: blender ****ing sucks]

Why isn't bevel working only for the selected vertexes in the same direction?

I tried merging by distance but the result is the same.

Comment: Use select non manifold to find any modelling issues and recalculate normals. It looks very much like a modelling issue.

Comment: Thanks! It turned out that face orientation was random(?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the faces are flipped and the *Bevel tool* doesn't like it :).

You can recalculate them through *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*.
Or flip them manually through *Mesh > Normals > Flip*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it came from scaling; I scaled around and some faces flipped even though in solid view it looked ok.

Comment: One more thing: what are you using to create gifs?